# how to replace goto part in c

Tags: c, goto

First, enter the coordinates of the vertex of the square. and each coordinate can not exceed 1000.
Second, enter the current location of the coordinates. location of the coordinate cannot exceed square.
and i want to find the minimum distance from coordinates to square.
This is the content that i want to make. So i made the code below.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void min_comparison(int a, int b, int c, int d); 

typedef struct coordinate {
    unsigned int x; unsigned int y; 
    unsigned int w; unsigned int h; 
}coord;

int main()
{
    int nomi1;
    int nomi2;

    coord cod;

    presentcoord:
    printf("enter the coordinates of the vertex of the square: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &cod.x, &cod.y);

    if (cod.x >= 1001 || cod.y >= 1001)
    {
        printf("The vertex coordinates cannot exceed 1000.\n");
        goto presentcoord;
    }

    presentloca:
    printf("enter the current location of the coordinates: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &cod.w, &cod.h);

    if (cod.w >= cod.x || cod.h >= cod.y)
    {
        printf("location of the coordinates can't excced %d, %d.\n",cod.x-1,cod.y-1);
        goto presentloca;
    }
    printf("\n");

    nomi1 = cod.x - cod.w;
    nomi2 = cod.y - cod.h;

    min_comparison(cod.x, cod.y, nomi1, nomi2);
}

void min_comparison(int a,int b,int c,int d) 
{
    int min; int min1; int result;
    if (a > c)
        min = c;
    else min = a;

    if (b > d)
        min1 = d;
    else min1 = b;

    if (min > min1)
        result = min1;
    else result = min;

    printf("minimum distance from coordinates to square is %d.\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

I looked it up on Google and it said "goto" is a bad code.
so i want to know how i replace the "goto" part of my code.

and English is not my first language.
So point out the wrong English expression, too.
I'd appreciate it if you let me know.

Comment: Some may argue that `goto` is OK if you use it for *forward* jumps to some cleanup part of a function. But backward jumps are hardly ever acceptable. You can replace the part between the jump label and the `goto` command with a loop. You only need to adjust the controlling conditions accordingly.

Comment: Learn how to use `while` loops.

Comment: @Neil Either it's a good fit for CR, or it's not yet achieving its goal. It can't be both :-)

Comment: @Mast what I meant was, first get it to work properly, then I think it would be suited for CR. :) Also, turn up compiler warnings; ideally you should return a number and display it in the main programme.

Comment: Questions are generally of higher quality if they demonstrate the problem using a [mre]. I do not believe that it was necessary to provide so much code in order to demonstrate the problem. A shorter program would probably have been sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily transform your code.
This part

```c
    presentcoord:
    printf("enter the coordinates of the vertex of the square: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &cod.x, &cod.y);

    if (cod.x >= 1001 || cod.y >= 1001)
    {
        printf("The vertex coordinates cannot exceed 1000.\n");
        goto presentcoord;
    }
```

can be reduced to this generic form:

```c
label:
   <do something>
   <Check if we are done>
   <If not, goto label>
```

That can be transformed to a generic loop:

```c
   bool done = false;
   do 
   {
      <do something>
      <check if we are done>
      <if yes: done=true;>
      <else: Print message>
   }while (!done);
```

In your case this would be

```c
    bool done = false;
    do 
    {
      printf("enter the coordinates of the vertex of the square: ");
      scanf("%d %d", &cod.x, &cod.y);

      if (cod.x >= 1001 || cod.y >= 1001)
      {
        printf("The vertex coordinates cannot exceed 1000.\n");
      }
      else 
      {
        done = true;
      }
    } while (!done);
```

Comment: Neither is polluting a scope with variables that "clean up" control flow constructs like `continue` or `break`. It's as polluting as a `goto`'s label.

Comment: Of course the extra variable `done` could also be avoided by moving the check directly into the condition at the end if you don't want to "pollute" your scope.

Comment: The real question is why do you want to pollute *your* scope. All this talk of clean code going around and people follow their religious belief about software to the point of writing hot messes.

Answer (score 2):

The `do-while` version proposed by Gerhardh is fine. Another more compact alternative is this:

```
while(1)
{
  printf("enter the coordinates of the vertex of the square: ");
  scanf("%d %d", &cod.x, &cod.y);

  if (cod.x <= 1000 && cod.y <= 1000)
    break; // stop if input ok

  printf("The vertex coordinates cannot exceed 1000.\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work, (not tested). `continue` will act like a `goto` back to the beginning of the while loop and `break` will act like a `goto` to the end of the while loop.

```
while(1){
    printf("enter the coordinates of the vertex of the square: ");
    scanf("%d %d", &cod.x, &cod.y);

    if (cod.x >= 1001 || cod.y >= 1001)
    {
        printf("The vertex coordinates cannot exceed 1000.\n");
        continue;
    }

    break;
}
```

Comment: Why would you suggest a loop without condition and using `continue` exactly like a `goto`?

Comment: Because it's faster and less prone to fail. For your information `continue` doesn't act exactly like a `goto`, it doesn't need a label, this makes it easier to use. It's also easier to adapt old code, using my method.

Comment: I doubt it is faster. You can use `continue` in a different way but here in this code it acts exactly like a `goto`. I would regard this not significantly better than a plain `goto`.

Comment: I would be more concerned with not checking the return value for `scanf` leads to UB.

Comment: The only difference between `goto` and `continue` is that `continue` can only jump non-conditionally upwards. And the general consensus is that code using these jump keywords should only be tolerated if it jumps downwards, never upwards. IMO the presence of `continue` in a C program is almost a dead certain indication of a loop that should be rewritten in better ways.

Comment: Except continue *does not* jump "upwrads". It jumps to the end of the current loop, hence downwards. This is self-evident enough when a for loop's epilogue (the increment) is executed upon a continue statement, or the condition is evaluated in a do-while loop. The flak `continue` and this answer get is ludicrous religious BS.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is kind of a brief code review, but I think it is welcomed by the OP. I'm not going to touch on the loop, which is covered by the other answers.

Initially, I was under the impression that `coord` is more of an [axis-aligned box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_bounding_box#Axis-aligned_minimum_bounding_box), but saw that it is actually two separate [coördinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinate_system). I would expect them to be one point. This is working with two-dimensions,

```
struct coord { unsigned x, y; };
```

Then one could write,

```
unsigned minimum_distance(const struct coord point, const struct coord enclosing_square);
```

`min_comparison` or `minimum_distance` should ideally be self-contained (`nomi1 = cod.x - cod.w` should be in the function) and return the minimum distance, not print it. If you want signed distances (vectors?), then I think a signed coödinate would be good.

One has to check the return values of [`scanf`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fscanf.html). Here, the return value is: `EOF`, 0, 1, or 2. Even just,

```
if(scanf("%d %d", &cod.x, &cod.y) != 2) exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
```

would be much better when faced with unexpected inputs.